# ulimit for windows

Tags: windows, ulimit, process-accounting

Are there true ulimit for windows?
I'm finding ways/programs how to prevent one program eating 100% cpu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[windows system resource manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755056.aspx) is the tool to set cpu limits per process, and adds process accounting interfaces.  In older versions of windows this was what was on the second disk that no-one ever installed.  In 2008 its a feature to be enabled.  Its generally not as important on a windows system (from a resource control perspective) than a unix one as "nice" is built into the OS and process priority (with certain exceptions) can be changed on the fly in the gui, in addition under windows vist and above disk IO can also be prioritized (by default this is based off of the priority of the process).  [There is an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549710(VS.85).aspx) that lets you set disk IO priority explicitly but I am unaware of any utility to let you directly change just disk IO priority

Comment: Is there something similar available on newer Windows Server versions? I read on the wikipedia that somehow Hyper-V should be used, but that seems a bit heavy handed.

Comment: the closest modern option I believe is windows containers

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like **Windows System Resource Manager** which has similar features to ulimit in that you can set CPU or memory limits on a process, user or session.  This was available on Windows 2003 Enterprise and later.

More information is available on [Technet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732553(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)(2008 R2 specific) or here is the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Resource_Manager).
[image: WSRM Screenshot]

---

A third-party option would be **[FasterWin](https://www.uwin4u.com/)** which is strictly for setting CPU quotas on processes.
[image: FasterWin]

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to right click the process in `Task Manager` and change the priority.

Comment: if you machine is idle, then the run away process will still eat 100% cpu, so this is kludge. you can't really beat unix for process accounting, unless windows 3.1 has had those tools added.

Comment: @user - limiting a process that is otherwise idle to something less than 100% usage is pretty much the definition of kludge unless you are considering power management.  Of course, ulimit can be used for more useful things.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at: http://threadmaster.tripod.com/

there also is a GUI for configure it: http://timwells.net/content/threadmaster-gui